# Adapter design pattern and memory management in C++

Tags: c++, oop, memory-management, inversion-of-control, adapter

Consider the following situation: I have a C++ module which takes an XML node as input, converts it to some other data structure, and returns the result.

Right now this module is implemented using [TinyXML](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/index.html), so it takes TinyXML classes as input (specifically, a TiXmlNode). This is an issue, because it forces anyone wanting to use my module to use TinyXML for representing the entire document tree. For example, if a [RapidXML](http://rapidxml.sourceforge.net/manual.html) user wants to use my module, he won't be able to, because the module expects a TinyXML node (and subsequent children), not a RapidXML one. Obviously, this is bad design because of poor reusability.

To solve this problem, I'm willing to apply the [Dependency inversion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle). So I design this extremely simplified, DOM-like interface:

```
class Node
{
    public:
        enum Type { TYPE_ELEMENT, TYPE_TEXT };

        virtual ~Node() { }
        virtual Type getType() = 0;
        virtual Node* getParentNode() = 0;
        virtual Node* getPreviousSibling() = 0;
        virtual Node* getNextSibling() = 0;
};

class Element : public Node
{
    public:
        virtual ~Element() { }
        virtual const char* getName() = 0;
        virtual Node* getFirstChild() = 0;
        virtual Node* getLastChild() = 0;
        virtual const char* getAttribute(const char* name) = 0;
};

class Text : public Node
{
    public:
        virtual ~Text() { }
        virtual const char* getText() = 0;
};
```

I then implement these interfaces using the [Adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) design pattern, wrapping the equivalent TinyXML classes. Or at least I try:

```
class AdapterNode : public Node
{
    private:
        const TiXmlNode& node;
    public:
        AdapterNode(const TiXmlNode& node) : node(node) { }
        virtual Node* getFirstChild() { Uh... oh, wait.
```

You can see that I'm heading into a memory management nightmare: I'm supposed to return a preexisting, already-allocated Node here. And indeed I have a preexisting, already-allocated TiXmlNode (accessible through `node->FirstChild()`), but this is a TiXmlNode, not a Node! Writing `return new AdapterNode(node->FirstChild())` would result in an obvious memory leak, as the newly-allocated AdapterNode would never get `delete`'d by anyone.

A few solutions crossed my mind to solve this memory management problem, but most of them are somewhat ugly. I'm asking for advice here: what would be your preferred solution to this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the most notable disatvantage of chosen approach is a significant burden placed on the developer the abstraction layer. I'd say it'd as hard as turning RapidXml classes into TinyXml ones, so you wouldn't get anything with this new abstraction layer. BTW, you've already did a mistake there attempting to return 'new AdapterNode(node->FirstChild())' from Node::getFirstChild method: if the first child is an element you'll be unable to cast AdapterNode into AdapterElement. There is also performance and memory overhead, probably limiting reusability as well as tying to a particular XML library.

I've thaught of something like making Node (and also Element, Text etc.) itself a smart-pointer for the underlying implementation. E.g.:

```
class XmlApi;

class Node
{
public:
    void * getLowLevelInterface() const;

    XmlApi * getApi() const;

    ~Node();

    Node(Node const &);

    Node const & operator =(Node const &);

private:
    void * lowLevelInterface;
    XmlApi * api;
};

class Element : Node
{
};

class Text : Node
{
};

class XmlApi
{
public:
    // Node -> more specific interface conversions.
    virtual bool ToElement(Node const &, Element &) const = 0;
    virtual bool ToText(Node const &, Text &) const = 0;

    // Node memory management
    virtual void acquireNode(Node const &) const = 0;
    virtual void releaseNode(Node const &) const = 0;

    // Node API
    enum Type { TYPE_ELEMENT, TYPE_TEXT };

    virtual Type getType(Node const &) const = 0;
    virtual Node getParentNode(Node const &) const = 0;
    virtual Node getPreviousSibling(Node const &) const = 0;
    virtual Node getNextSibling(Node const &) const = 0;

    // Element API
    virtual char const * getName(Element const &) const = 0;
    virtual Node getFirstChild(Element const &) const = 0;
    virtual Node getLastChild(Element const &) const = 0;
    virtual char const * getAttribute(Element const &, char const *) const = 0;

    // etc.
};
```

Surely, it makes sense to add inline wrappers for appropriate methods from XmlApi to Node, Element and Text, but it's just a minor implementation detail.

Main advantage here is far less overhead (it's still there, e.g. converting strings to char const *) and making an implementation for particular Xml library is much more straightforward. You just unpack 'low-level' node pointer, pass it to 'low-level' API and pack the result. No (almost no, see strings conversion) memory management or complicated inheritance hierarchies. Implementations of Node, Element and other classes are fixed and should be written only once and the only changing part is XmlApi.

UPD: if you can make your library a header-only with templates you can even elminate all virtual methods calls overhead by turning XmlApi into a template parameter.

Comment: "BTW, you've already did a mistake there attempting to return 'new AdapterNode(node->FirstChild())' from Node::getFirstChild method: if the first child is an element you'll be unable to cast AdapterNode into AdapterElement." Oh, indeed, thanks. Well, I would probably have thrown in a switch when I saw it (although, I'm not sure it would generalize well).

Comment: "if you can make your library a header-only with templates" Well, if I could do that, I wouldn't even be asking this question…

Comment: "converting strings to char const *" You're assuming the implementation is dealing with STL strings internally. That's not necessarily the case ; in fact, TinyXML doesn't use STL strings in its default configuration.

Comment: @e-t172: I don't think that templates would solve this issue per-se. You'll still need some kind of abstraction layer, don't you?

Comment: @e-t172: I've supposed you'd like to have abstraction layer for as many Xml libraries as possible. Then you'll have to deal with BSTR's from MSXML, XMLCh const */XMLString from xerces-c and so on.

Comment: Regarding the solution you're proposing: well, I really like your idea of using an unique Adapter class and void* pointers to maintain context without resorting to wrapper classes. It doesn't look very pretty (in fact, it smells more like C than C++) but nevertheless, it gets the job done without the disadvantages of the other solutions. I'm marking your answer as accepted, at least until someone comes up with a better one.

Comment: "I don't think that templates would solve this issue per-se. You'll still need some kind of abstraction layer, don't you?" Well, yeah, but the whole issue gets a lot simpler when you don't have to worry about object polymorphism: I could just make concrete template classes instead of abstract ones and then return everything by value.

Comment: @e-t172: regardin 'new AdapterNode(node->FirstChild())', I've this to illustrate difficulties one might face implementing these adapters. You've thought about it's design, you have time to implement and test it. Now imagine a poor guy trying to implement this for his XML library. He can make just the same error and without access to sources of your module he'll probably just get an unexpected error from inside you code and will have no idea what and where went wrong.

Comment: You're right, but this pretty much applies to every situation where your code gets called from another's code. No worries though: the module I'm writing is open source, so it won't be hard for the user to diagnose the problem inside the module.

Answer (score 3):

**Simple solution : use a smart pointer.** (smart pointers are the "simple" way to go to determine the lifetime of objects)

For example, here the simplest would be to create your object with new and then return it in a std::shared_ptr (or boost::shared_ptr).

**Optimized solution : use object pools** and provide a pointer or a reference type that makes sure you can't delete the provided object.

**Depends on your data : return by copy.**

Comment: Your third option is not possible because Node is abstract.

Comment: As far as the interface is concerned, your first option is akin to making Node's users delete Nodes after they're finished with them. That's totally feasible, but this means that each time get*() is called, a new Node will be allocated, resulting in tremendous heap activity (thousands of minuscule 8-bytes-or-so allocations). Sure it would work, but this is terribly inefficient. That's why I was looking for something a little more elegant.

Comment: Your second option sounds quite complicated for something which is supposed to be a thin wrapper around TinyXML.

Comment: First solution don't always imply creating a new node, not if you keep them somewhere with a shared_ptr inside your class, and provide them if they are already constructred. By keeping a shared_ptr and providing shared_ptr to external code, you make sure everyone have a valid instance until no one have use of it.
Second solution is if, even if thin, you want performance (speed &memory) optimization.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is create the whole tree at once, own it from some master object, and then return pre-allocated nodes from that.

```
XMLTree xml("xmlfilename.xml");
Node* ptr = xml.GetNode("beginning");
```

Also, prefer the use of strong types and `dynamic_cast` to some kind of `getType()` function.

Comment: dynamic_cast might not work across dll/so boundary. Also, getType is a part of standartized DOM API and consistency might be better here than theoretical purity/elegance/beauty.

Comment: Konstantin Oznobihin is right. About your solution: that's already what TinyXML does. I'm not sure I understand your proposal. Sure I could replicate the entire tree constructed by TinyXML in the Adapter classes, but that sounds like overkill for something which is supposed to be a thin wrapper. And inefficient memory-wise.